# Can't set member variable twice (NSManagedObject)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmanagedobject

I am getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to set a value inside a subclass of NSManagedObject for the *second time*.

I am using zombies but nothing is showing up in the console. Printing out the object using GDB I see that the object has the same memory address both times I try to set the value - not sure why though.

**Situation**:

1. I have a view (A) that, when a QR code is scanned, adds a subview (B) which in turn downloads XML that is then saved into a subclassed NSManagedObject.
2. Inside the subview (B) I navigate back (`removeFromSuperView` is called)
3. *Back in the original view (A)*
4. Next time, when the *same* QR code is scanned, it (A) finds the NSManagedObject from the database and attaches that to an instance variable on a new view (same type as B) that it then adds as a subview to the original (A).

In view B's `viewDidLoad` i always try to set the current date in order to track when a user "saw" that object. **This is where I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error**:

```
    self.currentPiece.piece_last_viewed = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Where `self.currentPiece` is the instance of a subclassed NSManagedObject that was attached in A when that object existed in the database.

I know that it is being released somewhere but I don't know where since managed objects take care of much of that on their own. The error only occurs the second time around that I try to set the value.

I have tried to make this clear. Please tell me if you want me to clarify it even more.
Thanks for the help (have worked on this for some hours now)

**UPDATE:**

Declaring the piece_last_viewed in HubPiece.h:

```
@interface HubPiece : NSManagedObject {

}

// ...

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *piece_last_viewed;
```

HubPiece.m:

```
@dynamic piece_last_viewed;

//...inside init method:

self.piece_last_viewed = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It is not due to the switching of subviews, that is ruled out. I then realized that I didn't save my changes either, so I introduced `save:` inside the subclassed NSManagedObject. I then got an earlier error the first time I try to save the entity instance (which saved during an app session, but the data vanishes if I quit the app entirely and then open it up again). So I thought using `[context save:&error]` would be a good idea :) ...but now that doesn't work and give me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The HubPiece itself is initialized from another class `HubPieceView.m` :

```
self.currentPiece = [[HubPiece alloc] initWithXML:pieceXML];
```

`self.currentPiece` is a class variable of type `HubPiece` and it first declared in .h file and then synthesized in .m file.

Then inside `HubPiece.m` the initializer looks like this:

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)pieceXML
{
    // Setup the environment for dealing with Core Data and managed objects
    HenryHubAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityHubPiece = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HubPiece" 
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // STORING values
    self = [[HubPiece alloc] initWithEntity:entityHubPiece insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    // ...setting variables with normal assignment: self.var = value;

    NSError *error;

    // Save fails
    if (![context save:&error] ){
        NSLog(@" ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Before you push B the second time, is the value of currentPiece correctly populated and intact?  How is piece_last_viewed declared?  Can you set piece_last_viewed before pushing view B (just to try to isolate viewB as the source of the problem or not.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ray, I did set it before pushing B and it didn't help so I have isolated it now to simply being about setting the variable when I am not allowed to.

Comment: How is piece_last_viewed declared?

Comment: Is there a fetch or save operation between setting piece_last_viewed the first time and the second time, or are you just re-using the originally fetched HubPiece?   Also, why are you using NSNumber instead of NSDate?

Comment: I am using NSNumber because it is a UNIX timestamp and also Core Data doesn't have a date field. I simple don't want to convert it back and forth between NSDate and NSInterval everytime I want the timestamp.

Comment: And yes I am trying to save the context each time that I change the value. But for some reason that gave me an error in the beginning when I first create the entire entity instance so I skipped it hoping it wouldn't bite me later...is it biting me now you think?

Comment: I actually get an error when trying to save the entity like so: `NSError *error = nil;
 [context save:&error];`
And I am fetching the object again with a predicate to get the object with a certain ID. Does thi cause conflicts? I do have an array I could use instead.

Comment: Core Data does indeed have a date field, so you can just use myEntity.myDateField = [NSDate date]; to capture the current date.

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to save?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ... trying use :`[managedObjectContext setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES]; ` now

Comment: Where/how are you obtaining the HubPiece object that you're trying to save?

Comment: I created my own subclass of NSManagedObject and an initializer called initWithXML that calls `self = [[HubPiece alloc] initWithEntity:entityHubPiece insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];` after setting some managedObject settings. Adding more code above.

Comment: You said "self.current_piece is a class variable" - what do you mean by that?  Is it retained when you assign something to it?   If you're crashing at the save, I suggest you step through that code with the debugger and see if you still have a valid context, and a valid current_piece at the time of the save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized my problem. I had been assigning values to the entity through with normal '=' assignment:

```
self.currentPiece.piece_last_viewed = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

When it should have been done:

```
[self setCurrentPiece.piece_last_viewed:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] ];
```

This is because it is a managed object which creates it's own accessors at runtime through the `@dynamic` compiler instruction.